# PFLogInViewController Customisation: intercept Facebook and Twitter Buttons to show Terms of Service

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to customise the behaviour of the Parse.com iOS PFLogInViewController. The idea is to intercept the touch of the Facebook or Twitter buttons. By this I want to show a screen, to make the user accept the Apps Terms of Service.

My current idea is to override the PFLogInViewController. Then I tried to remove the existing actions from the buttons and then to set new ones.

The issue that I have is, when I call:

NSLog(@"actions: %@",  [self.logInView.facebookButton actionsForTarget:self forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]);

I see the action: "logInUsingFacebook". Unfortunately this selector is not public...

Any idea?

THX,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the same situation recently and found the simplest solution to be creating a custom view controller and implementing calls to `PFFacebookUtils` directly, like so:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
    }
}];
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without rolling an entirely new controller? PFLoginViewController does so much...

Comment: Unfortunately, the easiest way is to roll a new UIViewController. You also get a lot of options that the PFLoginViewController does not provide. As my grandfather would say, "If it's worth doing, it's worth doing right."